# Add a linked appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration

I have several projects that share the same appsettings.json file.

When I add an appsettings.json file to each project on it's own, my projects starts up and loads configuration from these files.

I would like to have one file, that I link (Add -> Existing -> Add as Link), so that I have one single file to maintain.

Doing so, changes my .proj file to include the files :

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="..\Master\appsettings.Development.json" Link="appsettings.Development.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
<Content Include="..\Master\appsettings.json" Link="appsettings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

When I do a build, I can see both the appsettings in the bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1 directory.

My startup:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                var lConfiguration = hostContext.Configuration;

                ServiceConfiguration lOptions = lConfiguration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceConfiguration)).Get<ServiceConfiguration>();
                services.AddSingleton(lOptions);

            })
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
                    loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                );
```

However, when I debug my project, and I inspect the Configuration object, I can see all the configuration sources, but the appsettings source is empty.

I am confused, as the appsettings file is being built, but the configuration is not picking it up.

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you build your Configuration? It should look similar to this: `new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true).AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();`

Comment: I use out-of-the-box configuration. I would prefer not having to do the configuration manually. I've manually specified the config files perviously (as per your example), but don't understand why I need to do that now. I'm editing my question with my startup.

Comment: @PeterCsala no, I think you misunderstand the concept or my explanation. So I have one appsettings file that's living inside my "master" project. the other projects dont have a appsettings.json file in their source directory. When the project(s) build, it pulls the appsettings from the "master" project folder, and pushes it to the binary folder. This mechanic works great. The implementation in visual studio for this is great as well. It looks like there are files everywhere, but its really one file. When you edit it, it changes it everywhere. I'll be posting an answer to this now.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the working directory in .NET Core defaults to the source folder, and not the binaries folder. This means that it was looking for the appsettings.json file in my source folder, which would be there if I added an appsettings file manually, but when I linked it, it was not in the source folder.

The issue was resolved by changing the default working directory to the binary folder by doing this :

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location));
```

Answer (score 5):

There is one more way you can control from where the application will start. You can modify `launchSettings.json` file to add `workingDirectory` setting to your launch profile. Just point it to your bin output folder:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "Project1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "workingDirectory": "bin/Debug/net6.0",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```